# returning new line in notepad editor using javascript

Tags: javascript, string, mirth

I have this javascript code in a mirth channel that retrieves data from a query and sends the output to the destination in a .txt format. When a result is fetched, i want it to be on a single line. In other words, i want the result to be on a single line each time. I also tried "`<br/>`" but didn't work too.

```
var xmlMs = ''
var i = 0;
while (result2.next()){
        xmlMs += 'Count:' + ++i + "\n\r";
        xmlMs += 'No:' + result.getInt(1) + "\n\r";
        xmlMs += 'Date:' + result.getDate(2) + "\n\r";
        xmlMs += 'Time:' + result.getTime(2) + "\n\r";
 }
 test.add(xmlMs);
return test;
```

Comment: Line breaks for Windows applications should be `\r\n` not `\n\r`.

Comment: remove all the `+ "\n\r"` except the last one and listen to @Pointy

Comment: I want each of those record to be on a separate line, that was why i used it for each of them. However, when i removed it except the last one, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

must be `"\r\n"` in double quotes (or try only `\n` or double `\\n`)

- `\n` is new line
- `\r` return of cargridge today is not apply for some sistems
- `\r\n most used in windows`

**OR if is editor wysiwyg rich view** you must be insert a `<br>` or `<br />` tag

Answer (score 0):

You may add each of retrieved portions of data (such as 'No:'+result.getInt(1)) to the channel map and put them in a required order in the destination's template box (instead of ${message.encodedData}).

Comment: Unfortunately, when i use channel map in the source connector, it didn't accept it.

Comment: I've just checked, the mapping created in the Source connector is available under "Destination Mappings" on the Destination connector tab. This is under Mirth 3.1. Is your version different?

Comment: Yes, i use 3.1. When i create a channel map in source connector, it doesn't show up under Destination Mappings. But here is the good news, the \r\n works  and i didn't know. What happened was that i output to a text file and all i saw was a long string of result. In annoyance, i tried the result in smtp (which is my desired output) it works perfectly.

Comment: Too bad you cannot attach the channel here. It's hard to guess what you are doing differently so that the channel map is not available in both the source and destination.